# Controlling user privileges when using VLine

Tags: vline

I'm using VLine in a custom app with imported users, and am wondering if there's any way to limit the users a specific user is allowed to initiate a call with?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you mean the vLine WebClient when you mean custom app with imported users? In that case, there is no way to limit users yet. It will be great if you can file a feature request with exactly what you are looking for at https://vline.uservoice.com/.

If you are using the low-level APIs to build your app, of course you can do anything you want.

Comment: Actually I am using the low level API, so are you saying I need to decline all unwanted session initiations on the receivers end?  I was hoping the signaling server may have had the ability to drop messages based on allowed senders passed with authentication, or something along those lines.  How do you recommend we protect against the potential denial-of-service attack this opens up?

Comment: I meant all unwanted messages instead of unwanted session initiations

Comment: Yes the signal server has the ability to drop messages. But it is not exposed via API/dev interface yet. We plan to expose ACLs in the future, so you can configure who can send messages to your service etc. To answer your original question, can't you block on the sender's side (not show the call button for example on the sender side)?

Comment: Yes I can block showing the call button on the senders side, but that doesn't prevent a malicious person from initiating calls, sending messages, etc.